# In rails, can I access response.body in a action before it returns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails, can I access response.body in a action before it returns?

Say I want to do some final string replacements before it returns, can I get access to response.body i.e. the response that the view returns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a rack middleware to do such kind of replacements. Code for the rack is.

```
module Dump
  require 'rack'

  class Response
    def initialize(app)
       @app=app
    end

    def call(env)
       res=@app.call(env)
       res.body #change this and but also update res.length and header["Content-Length"]
       return res
    end
  end
end
```

include it in some file, lets call it dump_response.rb in RAILS_ROOT/lib folder. 
And line

```
use Dump::Response
```

in config.ru

Comment: so where would I get the response before it is sent, just before 'return res' ?

Comment: res is the response, its type is Rack::Response. res.body will get you body. you can change it as you like.

Answer (score 13):

Try after_filter in your controller.

You should be able to edit your response.body from there. For me, I needed to remove some ASCII characters in the xml hence I did this.

```
after_filter :sanitize_xml

def sanitize_xml
   #clean the response body by accessing response.body
```

Comment: I used this in Rails 4+, using `before_action`, then in the method `response.body = response.body.sub(/Regexp/, 'replacement')`. Worked well.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply overwrite rails render function in a controller, like this:

```
def render *args, &block
  super
  response.body.gsub!(/blah/,'')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The poor-man's way is to do this:

```
str = render_to_string "mycontroller/mytemplate"
str.gsub!(/blah/,'')
render :text => str
```